How do you cast an object to a class that has generic type in C#?
Struggling with this problem. I have a class that looks like this.
public class Result<T> where T: class, new()
{    
    public T? Value { get; set; }
}

I'm now trying to cast an object to this class, but I'm not sure how to handle the generic part.
object? funcValue = await GetResponse().Value;

// if (funcValue is Result<object> response) // this doesn't work
if (funcValue.GetType().Name.StartsWith("Result")) // The actual name is Result`1 when debugging
{
    var response = (Result<object>) funcValue; // code explodes here but I don't know the generic type to do a proper cast
    var res = response.Value; // trying to access the generic type from the Result class.
}



if you are getting a Result back why cast to a Result ? ... based on your comment // The actual name is Result1 when debugging  ... or if my question makes no sense, what do you expect GetResponse() to return? Thirdly, to add to the confusion, I don't see value ever declared in this code but it is used in your if block ...but again, perhaps I misunderstand.

C# is a statically typed language. To get the generic type at run-time you must know it at compile-time. The only thing you can do is use reflection to call a generic method that can use your type.

C# is a statically typed language. To get the generic type at run-time you must know it at compile-time. The only thing you can do is use reflection to call a generic method that can use your type.
Doing things like funcValue.GetType().Name.StartsWith("Result") to determine if your type is a Result<> is not the best way to go.
This is what works:
object? funcValue = (await GetResponse()).Value;

var type = funcValue.GetType();
if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    var gtype = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (gtype.Equals(typeof(Result<>)))
    {
        var ttype = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
        /* do stuff here with the run-time type of `T` in `Result<T>` */
    }
}

Now, to do something meaningful, I put this code together:
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _registry = new();

public class Response
{
    public object Value;
}

Task<Response> GetResponse() => Task.Run(() => new Response() { Value = new Result<Foo>() { Value = new Foo() } });

public class Result<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Foo { }

The dictionary allows me to register types that I want to do something with. So, for example:
_registry[typeof(Foo)] =
    (Action<Result<Foo>>)(rf
        => Console.WriteLine($"I have a Result<Foo>: {rf?.Value?.GetType()}"));

Now, I can write this:
object? funcValue = (await GetResponse()).Value;

var type = funcValue.GetType();
if (type.IsGenericType)
{
    var gtype = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (gtype.Equals(typeof(Result<>)))
    {
        var ttype = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();
        _registry[ttype].DynamicInvoke(funcValue);
    }
}

When I put all that together and run it, I get this:
I have a Result<Foo>: Foo

